# Unable to locate element in selenium when xpath is there

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the text of this linked in post: https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6761903191849230336/?updateEntityUrn=urn%3Ali%3Afs_feedUpdate%3A%28V2%2Curn%3Ali%3Aactivity%3A6761903191849230336%29

[image]

```
my_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6761903191849230336/?updateEntityUrn=urn%3Ali%3Afs_feedUpdate%3A%28V2%2Curn%3Ali%3Aactivity%3A6761903191849230336%29'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\Main\Documents\M&Saatchi\chromedriver')
driver.get(my_url)

sleep(5)
####MAIN PROGRAM#### - Page 1
source = soup(driver.page_source)

test = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="break-words"]')
```

Currently I get:

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@class="break-words"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.182)
```

I know this XPath exists using inspect element (see below)

[image]

Comment: Could you check again if you're trying to extract the span from the same page you find the element in inspect element; I have checked the page and can't seem to find the span you mention.(note, same version of Chrome here)

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't find the xpath for span class="break-words" inside Selenium but try this one.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6761903191849230336/?updateEntityUrn=urn%3Ali%3Afs_feedUpdate%3A%28V2%2Curn%3Ali%3Aactivity%3A6761903191849230336%29')
elem=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"p.share-update-card__update-text")))
print(elem.text)
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Outputs

```
Today welcome Natassia Badenhorst to the Razor team as a Group Account Director. Tash has been with us for a while as a freelancer but today we get to make her a permanent member of the team and we couldn’t be happier.  #powerfulconversations M&C Saatchi Group South Africa
```